# ADO SQL: No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: sql, vbscript, ado

Can someone please check my sql statement. I've checked that each variable a to e does have a value. And I am calling all the correct columns. I'm just not sure if my statement is correct.

But I am getting a error: No value given for one or more required parameters.

This is being run in a HTA vbscript.

```
sub updateUser(a,b,c,d,e)

SQL_query = "UPDATE users_tbl SET fname = '"& b &"', user_type = '"& c &"', email = '"& d &"', department = '"& e &"'  WHERE uid= '"& a
conn.Execute(SQL_query)

end sub
```

Comment: Why no command object? The above is very unsafe.

Comment: I mean it is open to sql injection. A command object http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_command.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `uid` is character type, use this:

```
SQL_query = "UPDATE users_tbl SET fname = '"& b &"', user_type = '"& c &"', email = '"& d &"', department = '"& e &"'  WHERE uid= '"& a &"'"
```

if it numeric type, use this:

```
SQL_query = "UPDATE users_tbl SET fname = '"& b &"', user_type = '"& c &"', email = '"& d &"', department = '"& e &"'  WHERE uid= " & a
```

Note, that your manner of using parameters is security prone.

Comment: thank you, the latter example worked. I think it was the ' that was causing the problem. I will look into the command object to prevent injection. Thanks again.